# Nonlinear model Fit

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am trying to fit my data to the function:
a + (b*(c/2)^2)/((T - d)^2 + (c/2)^2)

I entered
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data,
a + (b*(c/2)^2)/((T - d)^2 + (c/2)^2), {a, b, c, d}, T]

However it returned
[0.747-533.437/(260.512+<<1>>^2)]

How can I know the best fit value of each parameter?

```
data = {{1., -0.58}, {2., -1.507}, {3., -0.932}, {4., -0.3}, {5., \
-1.531}, {6., 0.193}, {7., 
   0.873}, {8., -0.697}, {9., -0.147}, {10., -0.114}, {11., -0.172}, \
{12., -1.847}, {13., 0.636}, {14., -0.846}}/
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  a + (b*(c/2)^2)/((T - d)^2 + (c/2)^2), {a, b, c, d}, T]
```

Comment: You need to post complete **reproducible** code with data (at least sample).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thanks for the reproducible code.  Just use `nlm["BestFitParameters"]` or better yet `nlm["ParameterTable"]` which also gives you measures of precision for each parameter.  But don't be discouraged if the question is closed as these are available in the online documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While, @JimB left a valuable comment, I think that the following is much easier in this case.

```
data = {{1., -0.58}, {2., -1.507}, {3., -0.932}, {4., -0.3}, {5., \
-1.531}, {6., 0.193}, {7., 
   0.873}, {8., -0.697}, {9., -0.147}, {10., -0.114}, {11., -0.172}, \
{12., -1.847}, {13., 0.636}, {14., -0.846}}
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  a + (b*(c/2)^2)/((T - d)^2 + (c/2)^2), {a, b, c, d}, T]
```

then you do

```
Normal[nlm]
```

> [image: output]

These are the same values that you would get from the suggestion in the comment.